# Java POJO collection attributes

Tags: java, collections

I have a POJO something like the one mentioned below. Here I'm referring `Set` collection attribute in `POJO1`. I understand that set does not contain duplicate. Do I need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `POJO2`? Using a `Set` here is not really going to helpful unless we override equals and hashCode methods? Please help me to understand little bit more on this context!

```
public class POJO1 {

        private String name;
        private Set<POJO2> pj2;

        public Company(){
            pj2 = new HashSet<>();
        }

        //setter and getter methods

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the only way for Java to understand which objects are duplicates is to call `equals()` method. Default implementation of `equals()` checks that references of two objects point to the same location in memory.

But depending on exact implementation of your `Set` you might need to override `hashCode/equals` or implement `Comparable` interface.

Since you put objects of `POJO2` into `HashSet` you need to verride `hashCode`equals`methods in`POJO2` class.

Answer (score 0):

You do like this

```
import java.util.Set;

public class POJO1 {

    private String name;
    private Set<POJO2> pojo2;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<POJO2> getPojo2() {
        return pojo2;
    }

    public void setPojo2(Set<POJO2> pojo2) {
        this.pojo2 = pojo2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        POJO1 pojo1 = (POJO1) o;

        if (name != null ? !name.equals(pojo1.name) : pojo1.name != null) return false;
        return pojo2 != null ? pojo2.equals(pojo1.pojo2) : pojo1.pojo2 == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (pojo2 != null ? pojo2.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Learn more at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: what is 31 referring in the above hashCode method?